# How to sort a column for mixed number of KB file size and MB file size in Microsoft excel

Tags: excel, csv

I have an excel file that contains the name and size of the file. Below is the sample structure I have in excel file.  I have around 10000 rows and I want to sort them by file size. Is there a tool available in Excel that can do this?

[image]

Comment: Use a helper column where you convert both of them to same unit and then sort using that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming SIZE is always "number space measurement" you can use:

```
=SORTBY(A1:B7,BYROW(B1:B7,LAMBDA(x,DROP(TEXTSPLIT(x," "),,-1)*VLOOKUP(DROP(TEXTSPLIT(x," "),,1),$G$2:$H$4,2,FALSE))),1)
```

Where `A1:B7` is your array to sort, `B1:B7` is size array and `$G$2:$H$4` is helper table. Adjust last `SORTBY` parameter to `-1` if descending sorting is needed.

Result:

[image]

With older versions use helper column something like this in `C1`:

```
=VLOOKUP(RIGHT(B1,2),$G$2:$H$4,2,FALSE)*LEFT(B1,FIND(" ",B1)-1)
```

dragged down and the use Data -> Sort and sort by column `C`:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me where do keep the vloopup formula ? is it in helper column? Can you apply the formula in https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e-gsEdmc-VRiltoH8OQUwVs50dvlo66jsPPcQYGNRs8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The first formula will not work in google sheets without modification. I have applied second formula and sorted descending

Comment: Woow great. Big thanks for applying the formulas directly in sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here, a solution that spills the entire result and there is *no need to use a helper column*. We use `KB` as the reference unit and use the relationship among different units as the power of `1000`, i.e. `1MB=1000KB`, `1GB=1000^2KB`, `1TB=1000^3KB`, `1PB=1000^4KB` and so on:

```
=LET(in, A2:B4, s, DROP(in,,1), n, TEXTBEFORE(s, " "), u, TEXTAFTER(s, " "),
 m, 1000^(XMATCH(u, {"KB","MB","GB","TB","PB"})-1), SORTBY(in, m*n))
```

We use `XMATCH` to obtain the index position and it is used to build the power, therefore the order is relevant (from lower to higher units). Since all units have a common suffix (`B`), you can write the array of units like this too: `{"K","M","G","T","P"}&"B"`.

Here is the output:
[image: output]

If the relationship cannot be established as the power of a common unit, then you can use `XLOOKUP` instead. I am using the same conversion rules, just for illustrative purposes:

```
=LET(in, A2:B4, s, DROP(in,,1), n, TEXTBEFORE(s, " "), u, TEXTAFTER(s, " "),
 m,XLOOKUP(u,{"KB","MB","GB","TB","PB"},HSTACK(1,1000,1000^2, 1000^3,1000^4)),
 SORTBY(in, m*n))
```

For example, it can be used to convert from the International System Metric to US System Metric.

**Note**: In this case, I prefer to use `TEXTBEFORE` and `TEXTAFTER` because both of them work as expected when the input is an array. There is no need to iterate over each cell. `TEXTSPLIT` doesn't work like that, you would need to iterate over each element or join the array then split it again: `TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",,s)," ", ",")` and extract each column, that would result in a more verbose formula. Similarly using `BYROW`:

```
=LET(in, A2:B4, s,DROP(in,,1), su, BYROW(s,LAMBDA(x, LET(nu, TEXTSPLIT(x," "),
 n,TAKE(nu,,1), u,DROP(nu,,1),m, 1000^(XMATCH(u, {"KB","MB","GB","TB","PB"})-1),
 m*n))), SORTBY(in, su))
```